# how to control the appsettings.json deployment based on environment in .Net Core

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-3.1, appsettings, .net-core-3.1

I have `ASP.Net Core 3.1` application & it has environment based `appsettings.json` as

- appSettings.UAT.json
- appSettings.Dev.json
- appSettings.Prod.json

When the app is published/deployed to any env say **UAT**, all the appsettings.json gets deployed to the UAT machine.

***The requirement is that if the machine/env is UAT, then only below appSettings should be deployed***

- appSettings.json
- appSettings.UAT.json

& if the env is Prod then

- appSettings.json
- appSettings.Prod.json

I know the other way is to store/fetch configuration from Environment variables rather appSettings.json but for now that has extra cost for me.

Thanks!

Comment: Hello Kgn-web, do you have a recommended way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This can be controlled by setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable on the UAT machine to UAT.

The defaults that .net core ships with is Development, Staging and Production.

You can find more information from the MS Docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1#set-the-environment

Answer (score 0):

You can set up the `"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"` variable against your website in IIS.

Open the "Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.

- Go to the Website where you want to set the environment variable.
  Find the "Configuration Editor".
- In the "Section" part of Configuration Editor, select
  system.webServer/aspNetCore in the left dropdown select
  ApplicationHost.config.
- Click on `environmentVariables` then you will get the Current env
  variable. Add a new env variable.
- `name` will be `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` and `value` will be
  `Development[staging/Prod]`. In your case it will be `UAT or DEV or Prod`
- Close the window and restart the website.

Give a try with the above.